# Beginner having issues with system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I am completely new to Mathematica, so I hope my question isn't too basic. I have been trying to use Mathematica to solve a system of homogenous ODEs using, and no matter what method I try I always end up with an error from DSolve saying that my equations aren't being interpreted as equations. I have included a screenshot for reference. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Equations are written with Equal: == and nor with Set: =

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You needed to write the 3 equations using `=` and on the right side use `==`.  Make sure not to mix `=` with `==`.   `=` for assignment, and `==` for equation.

Something like this

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eq1 = x1'[t] == -x1[t] - 4*x2[t] + 4*x3[t];
eq2 = x2'[t] == -4*x1[t] - x2[t] + 4*x3[t];
eq3 = x3'[t] == -4*x1[t] - 4*x2[t] + 7*x3[t];
depvars = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]};
DSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, depvars, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is better also to write each equation on separate line and not include them all inside the `DSolve` command. This makes the command shorter, and makes it easier to change later and to also see what is going on.

Also with `DSolve` is is better to use `x1[t]` for dependent variable and not `x1` (i.e. add `[t]` explicitly) With `NDSolve` it is the other way around. Use `x1` instead of `x1[t]`.  You do not have to do this, but it makes it easier for later processing of the result.

If you look at help, I am sure there are many examples there also.

And next time please also post the plain text code you used so one does not have to type it from an image and end up making a mistake.